# React-Router client-side error handling after server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm using server side rendering for my React app but can't wrap my head around the logic for showing error pages when something goes wrong.

For example:

- User requests `/article/123`
- Something goes wrong while fetching the article
- I would like to show a `500` error page

The server side part was easy. I tell React-Router to serve my error component. So far so good.

But when the page is served, the client-side javascript is executed and it takes over rendering. React-Router see the url `/article/123` and loads the component that shows the article (but fails since the data is not present..)

**Is there a way to let the client-side know that we want to show the error component instead?**

The only think I could think of is the following: Add the error to the global redux state. Before rendering a component, check if the error is present in the global state and show the error component instead.. But the downside of this is that you have to implement that checking logic in all of your components. There should be some kind more elegant way to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways to implement client-side error handling; I find using Higher Order Components work best. You would create a wrapper component that checks for errors from the server response. If it finds one, serve the appropriate error page. If the HOC doesn't detect an error, serve the component the user originally requested.

Here's a great explanation on how to implement HOC: 
https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Comment: Thanks, I'm not working on a React project at the moment but will look into this later!